# Olat 7.6 to latest OpenOlat migration issue in windows

Tags: migration

We have 'Olat 7.6' version installed in Windows Server 2012 server since a few years. It is working fine but now we thought of migrating it to 
latest version of OpenOlat.

I have restored backup to another Windows Server 2012 system. It is working fine but when I migrate to OpenOlat I am getting errors and application is not working.

I followed below process what Florian was suggested earlier listed as below :
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openolat/lK7BySZ1Egw

Refer below server log.

```
00:32:26:181 - INFO - ThreadLocalAwareLogger - OLAT::INFO ^%^ N1-I1 ^%^ org.olat.core.util ^%^ n/a ^%^ n/a ^%^ n/a ^%^ n/a ^%^ n/a ^%^ Setting userdata root to: C://data//olat//dirs
00:32:26:183 - INFO - ThreadLocalAwareLogger - OLAT::INFO ^%^ N1-I2 ^%^ org.olat.core.util ^%^ n/a ^%^ n/a ^%^ n/a ^%^ n/a ^%^ n/a ^%^ Sucessfully extracted context root path as: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\openolat\
00:32:26:184 - WARN - ThreadLocalAwareLogger - OLAT::WARN ^%^ N-W1 ^%^ org.olat.core.util ^%^ n/a ^%^ n/a ^%^ n/a ^%^ n/a ^%^ No UTF-8 capable filesystem found! Error while writing testfile to filesystem ^%^ >>>stack of 1.cause::java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect ->  at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method) at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:883) at org.olat.core.util.WebappHelper.testUtf8FileSystem(WebappHelper.java:332) at org.olat.core.util.WebappHelper.init(WebappHelper.java:102) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1544) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
00:32:26:186 - WARN - ThreadLocalAwareLogger - OLAT::WARN ^%^ N-W2 ^%^ org.olat.core.util ^%^ n/a ^%^ n/a ^%^ n/a ^%^ n/a ^%^ No UTF-8 capable filesystem found! Could not read / write UTF-8 characters from / to filesystem! You probably misconfigured your system, try setting your LC_HOME variable to a correct value. ^%^ cause:n/a
00:32:26:187 - WARN - ThreadLocalAwareLogger - OLAT::WARN ^%^ N-W3 ^%^ org.olat.core.util ^%^ n/a ^%^ n/a ^%^ n/a ^%^ n/a ^%^ Your current file encoding configuration: java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset().name()::windows-1252 (the one used) and your system property file.encoding::Cp1252 (the one configured) ^%^ cause:n/a
00:32:33:632 - WARN - GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor - Invalid JavaBean property 'actionController' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void org.olat.core.extensions.action.GenericActionExtension.setActionController(org.olat.core.gui.control.creator.AutoCreator)]: [public void org.olat.core.extensions.action.GenericActionExtension.setActionController(org.olat.core.gui.control.creator.ControllerCreator,java.lang.String)]
00:32:33:669 - WARN - JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
00:32:33:670 - ERROR - JDBCExceptionReporter - Table 'olat.o_noti_pub' doesn't exist
00:32:33:733 - INFO - MBeanExporter - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
00:32:33:743 - INFO - ThreadLocalAwareLogger - TaskExecutorThread finished
00:32:33:744 - INFO - SchedulerFactoryBean - Shutting down Quartz Scheduler
00:32:33:745 - INFO - QuartzScheduler - Scheduler schedulerFactoryBean_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
00:32:33:745 - INFO - QuartzScheduler - Scheduler schedulerFactoryBean_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
00:32:33:745 - INFO - QuartzScheduler - Scheduler schedulerFactoryBean_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete.
00:32:33:766 - INFO - AbstractSessionFactoryBean - Closing Hibernate SessionFactory
00:32:33:766 - INFO - SessionFactoryImpl - closing
00:32:33:772 - INFO - ThreadLocalAwareLogger - 
00:32:33:772 - INFO - ThreadLocalAwareLogger - *********************************************
00:32:33:773 - INFO - ThreadLocalAwareLogger - *                SHUTDOWM                    
00:32:33:773 - INFO - ThreadLocalAwareLogger - *********************************************
00:32:33:774 - INFO - ThreadLocalAwareLogger - * Application:   OpenOLAT
00:32:33:774 - INFO - ThreadLocalAwareLogger - * StopTimeStamp: Tue May 17 00:32:33 PDT 2016
00:32:33:775 - INFO - ThreadLocalAwareLogger - *********************************************
00:32:33:775 - INFO - ThreadLocalAwareLogger - 
00:32:33:777 - ERROR - ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailManager' defined in file [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\openolat\WEB-INF\classes\org\olat\core\util\mail\_spring\mailContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.olat.core.logging.DBRuntimeException: Error in list()
```

1. Earlier in olat 'web.xml' file      encoding="ISO-8859-1" is set.
2. And in properties file useOldUTF8Behavior=true is set.

I tried different ways but nothing is worked.

Let me know if you need any further details.

Thanks & regards,
Naresh

Answer (score 0):

I answered your question on the OpenOLAT mailing list:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openolat/3_mGe2ACE2o